# crash while drawing a gradient

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am getting following crash:

```
-[Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1e5ed7f0
```

---

```
void drawLinearGradient(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect, CGColorRef startColor, 
                                        CGColorRef  endColor)
{
    UIColor *start = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:startColor];
    UIColor *end = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:endColor];
}
```

Comment: is possible to see the other part of your code?

Comment: Turn on Zombies and reproduce the crash.

Comment: Looks like your problem is startColor and endColor is getting deallocated before you send.

Comment: UIColor *start = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:startColor];
here i am getting -[Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1e5ed7f0. plz help.